# Simplest possible HTML page with Polymer Paper Elements

Tags: polymer, web-component, polyfills

How to create the simplest possible html page which uses Polymer Paper Elements?

I would like to have a single html file which loads all reqired libraries from elsewhere (CDN). Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Polymer Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <paper-button>hello world paper button</paper-button>
  </body>
</html>
```

This obviously does not work, because `<paper-button>` is not known to browsers. So what do I have to include to make it work on all current browsers?

Is it possible without downloading any libraries myself and having to place them on my webserver beside my html file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Polygit](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/polygit) a CDN like tools for Polymer

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Polymer Simple</title>

    <base href="http://polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/">

    <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
    <link rel="import" href="paper-button/paper-button.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <paper-button raised> Hello World!</paper-button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is [codepen](http://codepen.io/jeanpokou/pen/eprMEQ) with polygit, you can fork kit

Comment: This doesn't work for me, and http://polygit.org/ now tells me "Polygit is deprecated and only compatible with ..." something.